# jQuery method to obtain contents of H2 Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="new_subscribed_threads" class="block">
<h2 class="blockhead">Subscribed Threads with New Posts: (0)</h2>
```

I am using the $.get method to obtain the content of another page on the same server. I want to store the contents of the H2 Tag in a variable and I am confused about how to get the H2.

I tried this:

```
var MyVar = $(results).find("new_subscribed_threads.h2").html();
```

But I don't think I am on the right track.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: try this $(results).find("new_subscribed_threads h2").html();

Comment: *`new_subscribed_threads.h2`: Selects any new_subscribed_threads element with a class attribute that contains the word h2* — http://tux.theopalgroup.com/cgi-bin/css3explainer/selectoracle.py

Comment: `$(results).find("#new_subscribed_threads h2").html();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is should be like this:

```
var MyVar = $(results).find("#new_subscribed_threads h2").html();
```

or

```
var MyVar = $(results).find("h2.blockhead").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't think I am on the right track.

Yes, you're totally off actually. You don't want to use a class selector `.h2`, but

- [an id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
- [descendant syntax](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)
- and [an element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as this:

- Find the position of the h2 tag
- Access it and get the content via html()

It looks something like:

```
var s= $('div.block >h2').html();
console.log(s);
```